# Removing words from classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with class `tab-detector one active` and this function:

```
$(".tab-detector").click(function (e) {
    var classList = $(e.target).attr('class');
    classList.replace("tab-detector","");
    classList.replace("active","");
    alert(classList);
});
```

I supposed that it should alert *"one"*, but I see *"tab-detector one active"* instead - `.replace()` didn't change anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: answer is correct, if you want to replace a class i suggest to use $(e.target).removeClass( "yourClass" );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`.replace()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) doesn't alter/mutate the initial string. You still need to assign the returned value back to the initial string.

Therefore it should look something like:

```
$(".tab-detector").click(function (e) {
  var classList = $(this).attr('class');
  classList = classList.replace('tab-detector', '').replace('active', '');
  alert(classList);
});
```

or:

```
$(".tab-detector").click(function (e) {
  var classList = this.className.replace('tab-detector', '').replace('active', '');
  alert(classList);
});
```

---

If your intent is to remove those classes, you *should* really be using the [`.removeClass()` method](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) instead, since that's exactly what it's designed for.

```
$(".tab-detector").click(function (e) {
  $(this).removeClass('tab-detector one');
});
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that in documentation. And no, I didn't want to actually remove these classes. Thanks :)

Comment: @Somaroton: Beware that there are two other possible issues with `.replace("tab-detector", "")`: 1. It will remove it even if it's *part of* another class, e.g., `"tttttab-detectorific".replace("tab-detector", "")` is `"ttttific"`. 2. It will only remove the *first* one, e.g., ``"tttttab-detectorific tab-detector".replace("tab-detector", "")`` is `"ttttific tab-detector"`. #1 is slightly tricky to solve (you can't just use a regular expression and `\b` markers). #2 is easily handled by using a regular expression and the `g` flag.